# Javascript DOM `null`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script in my head section:

```
 1| <script type="text/javascript">
 2| var inAccount = 0;
 3| if (inAccount = 0){
 4|   document.getElementById("L-out").style.display = 'block';
 5|   document.getElementById("User").style.display = 'block';
 6| }else{
 7|   document.getElementById("User").style.display = 'none';
 8|   document.getElementById("L-out").style.display = 'none';
 9| }
10| </script>
```

And the following code in my body section:

```
<div id="log">
<a href="#" class="in" id="Sign-up">Sign up</a>
<a href="#" class="in" id="L-in">Login</a>
<a href="#" class="in" id="User">Account</a>
<a href="#" class="in" id="L-out">Logout</a>
</div>
```

When I load the page I get this error message: 'null' is not an object. Referring to line 7.

Does any one know what might be happening?

Comment: `if (inAccount = 0)` should be with `==` or `===`. If you have your script in `head`, move it at the bottom of the page or add `onload`

Comment: are you sure your DOM is loaded when querying for the DOM Node?

Comment: @Spokey - Were do I add `onload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `==` when comparing variables in javascript
2. import jQuery in your page to make your js cross browser

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var inAccount = 0;
       if (inAccount == 0){
           $("#User").show();
           $("#L-out").show();
       }else{
           $("#Sign-up").show();
           $("#L-in").show();
       }
   });
   ```

here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wER6/

Comment: Thant fixes the error!

Answer (score 3):

The DOM elements referred in your script don't exist yet when the script is run (that's why the reference is null). To solve, just move that script on a `window.load`/*`domready`* event handler (or simply put that script as last child of the `body` element)

As a sidenote, the equality check should be made with `===`

Comment: Also worth pointing out @Spokeys comment, `if (inAccount = 0)` should contain `==` or `===`

Comment: So either place the script block below the HTML elements or react to the document load event.

Answer (score 0):

Dom is not ready.Wrap your code

```
window.onload = function(){ 
 if (inAccount == 0){
     document.getElementById("L-out").style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById("User").style.display = 'block';
  }else{
     document.getElementById("User").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("L-out").style.display = 'none';
   }
});
```

Comment: Where does `addEvent` come from? It's not a native method.

Comment: I tried that, but I get the error: "undefined" is not a function.  referring to the last line of code.

Comment: @FelixKling Edited its onload event.

Comment: @CodeApprentice Updated check now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `<script>` tags are at the bottom of your document [just above `</body>`] (for a couple of reasons):

1. Makes the page being rendered first priority (site appears faster to end-user).
2. The DOM objects will be created at that point, so JS will be able to locate the elements (like you're most likely having trouble with).

You *can* bind to document ready at the top, but I still am a firm believer of HTML first, JS second.

Also, when doing a compare in JavaScript, use `==` (or for a type-specific compare `===`). You're using an assignment in your first `if(...)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is your code is looking for elements that haven't actually loaded yet! What you can do to fix this is wrap your current if-else statement into a new function (`function init() {...}` for example), then in your body tag:

```
<body onload="init();">
```

Also, take care to use `==` or `===` in your if-statement.